# grails 3.0 with wschat / Web Socket Chat plugin

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

i am trying to install web socket chat 3.0.3 from this [page](https://grails.org/plugin/wschat) and i see this [page](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin)...

because i am using grails 3.0.5 then i put `compile "org.grails.plugins:wschat:3.0.3"` in my `build.grade` .. but i dont know why i cannot install that plugin...
i get this error

how to install web socket plugin?

```
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL            

    Total time: 1.868 secs      
    | Error Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime'. Type 'gradle dependencies' for more information

    C:\Users\User\Documents\ChatV3>
```

i get this error

```
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

testRuntime - Runtime classpath for source set 'test'.

+--- org.grails.plugins:wschat:3.0.3 FAILED  ==> HERE THE PROBLEM
```

for full log.. see this [link, log.txt](http://www.4shared.com/office/ZdLqfFtzba/log.html)

and [this my problem](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/issues/9#issuecomment-151548860)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should be going in to your build.gradle not application.yml...

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testwschat3/blob/master/build.gradle#L75 around there add:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:wschat:3.0.3"
```

where in this case its a local plugin in my example project

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmnUCJpxGRI
i cannot install that plugin :(
what must i do?